# Invalid suffix 'x50' on integer constant

Tags: objective-c, ads, mopub

I am integrating MoPub in my app, but ran into the following error when I should write the size on the ad banner:
Invalid suffix 'x50' on integer constant

```
self.adView = [[[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:@"adUnitCode" size:320x50] autorelease];
```

If it does't work to write the size as MoPub said, does anyone know How i can write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature is:

```
- (id)initWithAdUnitId:(NSString *)adUnitId size:(CGSize)size
```

so you need to supply a `CGSize`. That could be done with `CGSizeMake(320, 50)` or the constant supplied by MoPub: `MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE`.

Writing `320x50` looks like an invalid integer to the compiler and that is the reason for the description of the problem.

---

So, removing your ARC issue too, you need to import the constants

```
#import "MPConstants.h"
```

and your line will be:

```
self.adView = [[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:@"adUnitCode" size:MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE];
```

Comment: Thanks @wain, but now I get the following error: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease' and the error: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode.

Comment: Remove the call to `autorelease`. Remember that code you copy needs to be verified for your situation, it won't always 'just work'.

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting a CGSize struct for the `size:` parameter, so try:

```
self.adView = [[[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:@"adUnitCode" 
                                             size:CGSizeMake(320, 50)] autorelease];
```